# MS graph InvalidDeltaToken on events list next page

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

I'm getting an error when I call NextLink from the response of first delta.
Any ideas why it's happens?

first call:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/4ca91597-4091-4cce-856b-7472b3f9ade1/calendars/AAMkAGM3MDdhNGZlLWRjYTUtNGZkYS04NTcxLTU2OTNkZWEwNDlhYQBGAAAAAAAmh2PA4MC8QpGOM1iWfgeZBwCI_1RC5zxoQrQX6X2piZBLAAAAAAEGAACI_1RC5zxoQrQX6X2piZBLAAAAjD53AAA=/events/delta
```

response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(event)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/4ca91597-4091-4cce-856b-7472b3f9ade1/calendars/AAMkAGM3MDdhNGZlLWRjYTUtNGZkYS04NTcxLTU2OTNkZWEwNDlhYQBGAAAAAAAmh2PA4MC8QpGOM1iWfgeZBwCI_1RC5zxoQrQX6X2piZBLAAAAAAEGAACI_1RC5zxoQrQX6X2piZBLAAAAjD53AAA=/events/delta?$skiptoken=S-9EQM7OmIraj-ou9n4yBgQa6fEPxPaBcX7TFg2kKSyrl9s4t08HSSZnFF-gwy4A9E6Yg7ADWLv-z3JJ4D5p_galSKYHzmiN98EJV1ewagGy4vLP_Ccf6Ry5MQoXRx_NxwVr9hFfl2aiymXlEAMXUSGMaX9Yc7O2q6czmAFcCr_ZEL7TGy0sQqgOA7UzNZ64ocJyQRBMUjvuE19KlhqPkA.XaSRYkwmW-IAiW8ABt7Qi1gz7aHGDe2uF-m2RdF2lLM
...}
```

and on call NextLink I'm getting error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidDeltaToken",
        "message": "The value 'NCZUMk42WmtGWmFqZFdSVXh1VUVkb1EzUkNabkJtWVcxS2EwVnpRVUZPVmtWelJEQkNRVUZCUVE9PQ=='
of parameter '$deltaToken' is invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-27T19:04:42",
            "request-id": "6897b163-5d66-4223-8c01-ab40a0417c35",
            "client-request-id": "3455e667-c7e7-9c6d-e18e-5c94c37150c8"
        }
    } }
```

UPD.1

problem with header:

```
rPrefer = odata.maxpagesize=50
```

if you are MS's developer please open ticket.

Comment: By fixing the above header, it worked for you or still you can repro the issue? If yes, glad that you can share back the info back with the community.

Comment: of course it resolved my issue.

Comment: Glad to hear!! Thanks for confirming.