# InvalidDeltaToken on NextLink (Microsoft Graph Calendar)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

When I get the list of events using :

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/myemail@email.com/events/delta`

[Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHTto.png)

I get the link @odata.nextlink, but this link returns an error InvalidDeltaToken

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidDeltaToken",
        "message": "The value 'NCZVRzVYWmtGYVRtaHFiemxpWmxOYVNHaFRWVkpVVmsxbFZVNUJAHFUYRJKJNSDSDZCUVE9PQ==' of parameter '$deltaToken' is invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-12-04T06:57:25",
            "request-id": "5a96ac45-d7ed-4454-8597-eae1587c32",
            "client-request-id": "85679541-3618-b871-b880-f51191ab745"
        }
    }
}
// the ids have been modified !
```

[Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNw4A.png)

This issue occurs when the list of events has more than let say 200 elements (not sure exactly but over 175, I'm starting having the problem).

I can't find any workaround even using odata.maxpagesize, I'm still having the issue.

I'm using Microsoft Graph Explorer to reproduce the error.

Comment: Last time i remember [a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092283/ms-graph-invaliddeltatoken-on-events-list-next-page) where the similar issue was reported and i tried looking at it.

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: There is a conversation about this issue on Microsoft Doc : [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/186292/invaliddeltatoken-on-nextlink-microsoft-graph-cale.html?childToView=196262#comment-196262)

Comment: With the v1.0 endpoint and using calendarView (with a startDateTime and endDateTime),   it works fine. At the time of writing, the date range for the calendarView can't exceed 100 years...

Comment: I have tried to use a calendarview instead and not use the beta endpoint, but it seems that if there are too many events to collect, the request runs for a long timle before returning an UnknownError.

Comment: The only way I could make it work so far its to use a calendarview with a request header (maxpagesize). @Dev posted above a related thread with the maxpagesize but it works only with the v1.0 endpoint end not the beta endpoint.
Still waiting for a fix or then a workaround without using a calendarView.

Comment: Glad to hear that the workaround with maxpagesize helped. I go with general disclaimer to try implement v1.0/GA APIs as they're meant for production. But i love to test/play with beta APIs to know whats the new feature, how its going to work, if there is any feedback share it back - as its not meant for production and tend to break.